# Collision using Tilemaps

Tags: tiles, tilemap, maps

How do I get the player in a platformer to collide with tiles
My code for my for loop is

```
        for(var i = 0; i < game.map.length; i++) {
        for(var j=0; j < game.map[i].length; j++) {

            if(game.map[i][j] === 2) {
                drawImage(game.backgroundContext, game.images[0], game.x, game.y, 50, 50);
            }
            if(game.map[i][j] === 1) {
                drawImage(game.backgroundContext, game.images[1], game.x,game.y,50,50);
            }
            if(game.map[i][j] === 0) {
                game.backgroundContext.fillStyle = "#14FFDA";
                game.backgroundContext.fillRect(game.x, game.y, 50, 50);
            }
            game.x += 50;
        }
        game.x = 0;
        game.y += 50;
    }
```

I was thinking to put

```
        if(game.player.y >= game.y && game.player.y <= game.y+height) {
            game.player.falling = false;
        } else {
            game.player.falling = true;
        }
```

inside one of the if its equal to one (0 = background 1=floor)

Anyone have the annswer

**Edit** Image
[image]
(The player goes through the bricks)

**Edit** Due to downvotes nobody gets the bounty
If it gets back to 0 downvotes I will give the bounty away

Comment: Your first snippet appears to be the game / level setup, whilst the second snippet should be part of your game's main loop. You should not be checking collisions during setup, or (ideally) performing setup in your main loop...

Comment: I do that, its in my render loop.

Comment: If that WILL get more downvotes though, this community has to be fixed. It should be about helping, not downvoting.

Comment: This community _is_ about helping, but like all communities, we have [rules and etiquette](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/help) and we expect our members to adhere to them. Your question here has been poorly received, primarily (I would guess) due to the fact that it is little more than a code dump without a clear problem statement, and you don't seem interested in _improving_ your question so much as trying to bump it (which is not appropriate) and try to lord a bounty over other users (a bounty you don't fully control, anyhow), which is rude.

Comment: If @realUser404's answer, below, does not actually solve your problem, then you should clarify your question. I would suggest including some information about the context in which the code you have presented is called and information about what the state of the program is when you step through it in the debugger. Which of these conditions for detecting the collision do you _expect_ it to hit? What are the values of the relevant variables when it doesn't hit and passes through? If you can extract that info, you may even be able to arrive at the solution yourself.

Comment: @JoshPetrie I just want the player to collide with the floor. Not fall through it.

Answer (score 1):

There is something pretty strange in your code.

Your `game` has `x` and `y` attributes and you increment them in order to draw your scene. You then use the same `game.x` and `game.y` in your collision detection code, that does not make sense.

First of all you could just change your loop like this

```
for(var i = 0; i < game.map.length; i++) {
    for(var j=0; j < game.map[i].length; j++) {

        if(game.map[i][j] === 2) {
            drawImage(game.backgroundContext, game.images[0], j * 50, i * 50, 50, 50);
        }
        if(game.map[i][j] === 1) {
            drawImage(game.backgroundContext, game.images[1], j * 50, i * 50,50,50);
        }
        if(game.map[i][j] === 0) {
            game.backgroundContext.fillStyle = "#14FFDA";
            game.backgroundContext.fillRect(i * 50, j * 50, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Which allows you to get rid of these `game.x` and `game.y`.

Then concerning collision detection, you should parse all the `brick` tiles and check if `player.y + player.height >= brick.y` (in canvas y = 0 is on top of the screen). That means somewhere you should stock the brick elements.

This might look like this

```
detectCollision()
{
     falling = true;
     for (brick in bricks)
     {
         if (player.y + player.height >= brick.y)
         {
             falling = false;
             break;
         }
     }
}
```

If the floor is supposed to be linear all way long, you can make it even more simple. Just store the y position of the floor and check if `player.y + player.height >= floor.y` only once.

Comment: So how would I go about "storing" the bricks

Comment: You could use an array of objects. Did you try the simple way `player.y + player.height >= floor.y` ?

Comment: But I want it compatible with new tile sets, but the array would probably work!